# How to install latest Java version?

Tags: java, ubuntu, asdf, asdf-vm

How do I use the latest version of Java in [asdf](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf) without specifying a version number?

```
asdf install <name> latest
```

For example, I want to use Oracle GraalVM. I tried some operations but failed. How should I do it?

Here's what I did:

```
oracle-graalvm-21.0.1
```

This is the latest version and also what I need.

Try but failed:

```
asdf install java oracle-graalvm latest

Unknown release: oracle-graalvm
```

This works but I don't want to specify the version number:

```
 asdf install java oracle-graalvm-21.0.1
```

Comment: Have you tried `asdf list-all java` to see what is available?

Answer (score 0):

I think asdf does not directly support the "latest" keyword for specific plugins. However, you can achieve a similar result using asdf-vm's plugin-alias feature.

```
# Add a plugin alias for Java
asdf plugin-add java https://github.com/halcyon/asdf-java.git

# Set an alias for the latest GraalVM version
asdf alias java latest graalvm-21.0.1

# Install the latest GraalVM version using the alias
asdf install java latest

# Set the latest GraalVM version as the global version
asdf global java latest
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same. Taking a look at [asdf-java](https://github.com/halcyon/asdf-java), the syntax is as follows:

`asdf install java latest:openjdk`

You can also swap out the provider to be something else, like `latest:graalvm`

Hope that helps, happy coding!